# Results of OpenMP target directives on GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp

I'm using GCC to compile the following program which uses OpenMP's target directives to offload work to a GPU:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(){
  const int SIZE = 400000;

  double *m;
  m = new double[SIZE];

  #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for
  for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    m[i] = std::sin((double)i);

  for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    std::cout<<m[i]<<"\n";
}
```

My compilation string is as follows:

```
g++ -O3 test2.cpp -fopenmp -omptargets=nvptx64sm_35-nvidia-linux
```

Compilation succeeds, but quietly.

Using PGI+OpenACC, I'm used to a series of outputs that tell me what the compiler actually did with the directive, like so:

```
main:
  8, Accelerator kernel generated
     Generating Tesla code
     11, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
  8, Generating implicit copyout(m[:400000])
```

How can I get similar information out of GCC? `-fopt-info-all` is a big mess.